# Rich of VS Rich in

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adjectives

I know that we say that **something is full of something**, so why that doesn't apply to "**rich of**"? For instance:

> The country is **rich in oil**.

rather than

> The country is **rich of oil**

Comment: There is often no logic to which preposition applies in a given situation. You just have to know them.

Comment: I’ve added an “is” to your second example to make it similar to the first. If that wasn’t your intention, you should edit your question to remove it. You can see the changes I made by clicking the “edited” link above.

Comment: Offhand it's not easy to think of contexts where someone/something can be [ADJECTIVE] ***of*** [NOUN}. A couple that come to mind are *A poor man is **short of money*** and *Monday's child is **fair of face**.* There must be more, but I just can't come up with another right now (and even my second one there was a bit "dated", to say the least! :)

Comment: My brother said it was "good **of** me" to help him. My aunt said I was "good **for** nothing". My father said I was "good **at** soccer". My grandma said I was "good **in** parts".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica empty of? :) (the streets are empty of people/rubbish)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Good one! The fact that 1) You only suggested *one* more, and 2) It feels like another "quirky" one, like ***fair of face**,* both lend credence to my suspicion that there really aren't that many such expressions featuring ***of***. I'd almost like to ask for more examples on ELU, but I just know they'd closevote it for being a "list-type" question.

Comment: ... I can't even say [***heavy of heart***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heavy+of+heart%22) sounds "Victorian" to me. The truth is it sounds positively ***medieval**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica What about *free OF disease*?  But then there's *free FROM need* so we can't even say particular adjectives take particular pronouns. I think that English is much like quantum physics. The smallest bits don't obey sensible rules and everything gets really complicated :)

Comment: @ColleenV: It's not easy to disagree with ThePhoton's original point *(**You just have to know them**)*, but I think one thing many learners could usefully take on board is that there are an awful lot of contexts where *more than one preposition works* (besides plenty of other contexts where only one *particular* preposition works). It's not always a matter of *What is **the** "correct" preposition for this context?*

Answer (score 1):

As one commenter said, often there isn't much logic to which preposition sounds natural! However in this case, I would think about the meaning of the sentence without the prepositional phrase:

> The country is full.

This seems to be lacking information. We are left asking, full ***of*** what?

> The country is rich.

This is a complete thought; the country is generally wealthy. Now we could ask, ***in*** what areas is the country rich?

While this answer isn't based on a solid rule, I hope it's a helpful example of how to think through similar problems in the future!